# How to Reset the badgeValue after loading the screen in swift?

Tags: swift, badge

I want to reset the badge value of the tapItem if the user has seen the notification by visiting the screen.

With this code, I create the badgeValue. but it will never be reset:

```
func createBadgecount() {
    if let tapItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray! {
        let tapItem = tapItems[3] as! UITabBarItem
        tapItem.badgeColor = UIColor.black
        tapItem.badgeValue = "\(reports.count)"

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `badgeValue` of `selectedItem` in `tabBar` to `nil` if this `UIViewController` did appear.

So add this to `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem {
        tabItem.badgeValue = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set value nil in

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  if let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem {
    tabItem.badgeValue = nil
   }
}
```

Comment: @jo1995 i am glad to answerd you. Please upvote me and correct ans me if i am helpful to you.